# Add Icon to Browser Tab?

Tags: css

How do I add an icon to the browsers tab through CSS?

I tried to do this:

```
head
{

icon: 'images/favicon.ico';

}
```

But it says that it can't resolve the reference. Then I looked around on stackoverflow and other places, and I keep finding what appears to be HTML solutions and not just CSS solutions, unless that's impossible of course.

Comment: uhh...  What? what browser bar?  What is `icon`?

Comment: Do you mean a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687440/using-favicon-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you want to use HTML solution?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Because then I'll have to add that to all my pages separately, no?

Comment: @Vipar that is correct, it will need to be placed on every page. But, to my knowledge, no browser looks in stylesheet for a favico declaration.

Comment: That's why I asked if it was possible to do in CSS at all :P

Answer (score 0):

> CSS stylesheet not supporting to change favicon iamge inside tab

Add the below code inside head tag.
.ico or .png  image extension also support.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```